# How to fetch data from database in same input textbox after form submit?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, form-submit

I have next method where we use fom post to send date to database:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddDateToDatabase(StudyDateViewModel model)
        {
            var studyDate = model.StudyDate;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var personRepository = new StudentsRepository<PersonalInformation>())
                {
                    string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                    var changeStudyDate = personRepository.Get()
                                          .Where(c => c.UserId == userId)
                                          .FirstOrDefault();

                    changeStudyDate.StudyDate = studyDate;
                    personRepository.Update(changeStudyDate);
                    TempData["message"] = $"Well done. Your study date is {studyDate.Value.ToShortDateString()}. Don't forget to check email ";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("PersonalCabinet");
        }
```

This is my partial view where we call our method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddDateToDatabase", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" , id = "dateForm" }))
{
                <div class="input-group input-medium date date-picker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-start-date="+0d">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StudyDate, new { @class = "form-control", Value = Model.StudyDate })

            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn default" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Choose" class="btn btn-info"  />       
}
```

And we call our partil view next:

```
 @Html.Partial("AddDateToDatabase", new StudyDateViewModel())
```

So my question is how to get value from database in same input after form submit??  Because when I click submit value pass to server good but it dissapears from this input after reloading page? So What I should do in this case?

Comment: you'd have to return the populated model back to the page as part of the view, instead of creating a `new StudyDateViewModel()`

Comment: @ADyson yea , I thought about this . How can I return populated model in html.partial?

Comment: You can use `ajax` for pass data to action.

Comment: replace `new StudyDateViewModel()` with a populated object containing the model values. For this to be accessible in Razor you must have placed it somewhere accessible (e.g. ViewBag or TempData) during the action method which caused the view to be displayed.

Comment: @ADyson okay i tried this in my action method  ViewBag.studyDate = studyDate; Now Viewbag contains my date , but i don't understand what to do next ? I can't pass viewbag as second parameter into html.partial , u can see in my Html.TExtbox(new {value=}) i tried to add value but it dissapear data after submit too, can u provide a little bit code?

Comment: @ADyson i just don't understand what to write instread new StudyDateViewModel() because my partial view use model StudyDateViewModel()

Comment: @ADyson hmm it is work  , I pass to html.partial Model as second parameter. I don't know if it is correct

Comment: if it's working, how can it not be correct? Sorry I don't follow what you mean.

Comment: @ADyson I explain. I write Html.Partial("myPartial" , Model) and change from model StudyDateViewModel() to my domain model model PersonalInformation and now it's work , but why with view model doesn't work I don't know , if u see my method in controller then u can see that  i map my view model to domain.